# What is effect size?

Tags: interpretation, effect-size, definition

It might be silly question-want to have clarity of this concept.I was wondering if someone can elaborate meaning and examples of effect size in clinical research. How to interpret it accurately? How does one calculate it for example with OR?

Comment: Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size ? There's even a section on odds ratios there. That might help focus your question to be more specific. With such a general question, people might say a great deal without saying anything to help resolve your difficulties.

Comment: @Glen_b Sounds good. Thanks for your recommendation.